# What is the memoy size of a Java object array after it has been created?

Tags: java, arrays, memory

This probably doesn't even need asking, but I want to make sure I'm right on this.  When you create an array of any object in Java like so:

```
Object[] objArr = new Object[10];
```

The variable `objArr` is located in stack memory, and it points to a location in the heap where the array object is located.  The size of that array in the heap is equal to a 12 byte object header + 4 (or 8, depending on the reference size) bytes * the number of entries in the array.  Is this accurate?

My question, then, is as follows.  Since the array above is empty, does it take up 12 + 4*10 = 52 bytes of memory in the heap immediately after the execution of that line of code?  Or does the JVM wait until you start putting things into the array before it instantiates it?  Do the null references in the array take up space?

Comment: Just to give you some terminology, you are effectively asking if Java arrays are "[sparse arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array)"

Comment: Whether it's pointing to null or whatever, reference is reference, in this case it happens to be of type `Object`. But it's a good question, +1.

Comment: Oh, thanks guys.  I'm not sure how some of this knowledge slipped through the cracks for me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The null references do "take up space" -- the array's memory is allocated up-front in one chunk, and zeroed (to make all of the contents null references).  As an exercise, try allocating a huge array, one that will take up more space than your JVM's memory limit.  The program should immediately terminate with an out of memory error.

Comment: That was a great idea!  I maxed out the heap space once I got into the billions of elements.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will be helpful to you

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        System.gc();
        System.out.println("Before " + r.freeMemory());
        Object[] objArr = new Object[10];
        System.out.println("After " + r.freeMemory());
        objArr[0] = new Integer(3);
        System.gc();
        System.out.println("After Integer Assigned " + r.freeMemory());
    }
```

**Output**

```
Before 15996360
After 15996360
After Integer Assigned 16087144
```

Comment: This output is rather misleading; the array memory should be allocated at the `new Object[10]` expression.  You may be seeing the effects of statement reordering by the optimizer; there are no memory barriers here AFAICT.  (In other words, the optimizer may be swapping the `Object[] objArr = new Object[10];` and `System.out.println("After " + r.freeMemory());` statements around.)

Comment: How come you say that this is misleading ? This may resolve your problem

Comment: Because the output leads you to believe that the array memory is not allocated until it is assigned to.  However, what is likely happening is that the optimizer is *reordering statements* on you, and is simply moving the array allocation until after the second `println()` call.

Comment: I didn't know you could see free memory like this in Java.  It just seems like it's tough to account for differences in predicted amounts of memory being used, which must be due to the optimizer as @cdhowie said.  Useful, but not necessarily explaining how the memory is used exactly.